# how to make 2 conditions in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make  in "if" statement 2 conditions in componentDidUpdate. Here is my code:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (
      prevState.address_id !== this.state.address_id &&
      prevState.whoIsMetting !== this.state.whoIsMetting
    ) {
      console.log("hello")

    }
  }
```

It doesnt fire any events, but If I use them separately it works fine. I need to check for both statements at same time. Is possible to make 2 conditions in componentDidMount or is there any other  ways?

Comment: _but If I use them separately it works fine..._ well, when you check them separately then your condition is different isn't it

Comment: This will check if both `address_id` and `whoIsMetting` have changed. You might want to use `||` instead of `&&` to check if either value has changed.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I need to check them at same time , then if both true fire my function

Comment: @Caramiriel I need both states at same time , I don't need either

Comment: So the code you posted is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need them both true, you can chain them:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.address_id !== this.state.address_id){
           if( prevState.whoIsMetting !== this.state.whoIsMetting){
                // do stuff if both true;
           } else {
             // do stuff if first true and second false
           }
      } else {
          // do stuff if first false
      }
}
```

Comment: If the OP needs both conditions to be true when checking, his code should be working just fine. The answer I posted is just a making the same thing lengthier. Only thing I can think of is that the way the other components are working, his conditions are cancelling each other. Like either the first is true or the second. With my answer he can track which one.

Comment: @Dblaze47 Thanks! Thats what I want. I have mentioned couple times that I need both conditions to be true , why everyone keeps offering answers with single check or || statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the logic of your `if`, not the syntax. You can write any valid JavaScript inside a `componentDidMount`, as it is just a function like any other.

Writing two `if` functions like so:

```
if (prevState.address_id !== this.state.address_id)
...
if(prevState.whoIsMetting !== this.state.whoIsMetting) 
...
```

Is very different from checking for both statements at the same time with an `&&` operator. The && means both need to be true. If you want a way to check both of them and get the same result as if you were using two ifs (like above) then:

```
if (
      prevState.address_id !== this.state.address_id ||
      prevState.whoIsMetting !== this.state.whoIsMetting
    )
```

Will do the work, as you're checking one `OR` the other to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `&&` then the condition will be true if both of them were true otherwise if you want to execute the statement if one of them is true you can use `||` instead.

And if your condition

`prevState.address_id !== this.state.address_id`

is true it will check

`prevState.whoIsMetting !== this.state.whoIsMetting`

but if the first condition is false it won't check the second one and it will return false directly.